# Adding extra data to a view which is not present in table sql

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

I'm trying to return some data from a table joined with another. In addition, I want to return some more data in addition to what is there in the table already but these data should not be stored in the database.

Here's my person table

```
+-------+-------------------+
| name  | preferred_fruit_id |
+-------+-------------------+
| john  |                 3 |
| smith |                 2 |
| sam   |                -1 |
+-------+-------------------+
```

And fruit table

```
+------------+----------+
| fruit_name | fruit_id |
+------------+----------+
| apple      |        3 |
| orange     |        2 |
+------------+----------+
```

Here's my query for view

```
SELECT name, fruit_name
FROM person p,fruit f
WHERE p.preferred_fruit_id = f.fruit_id
```

I want the view query to return something like this adding "all" where preferred_fruit_id is -1.

```
+-------+--------+
| name  | fruit  |
+-------+--------+
| john  | apple  |
| smith | orange |
| sam   | all    |
+-------+--------+
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a `left join`.  This would be more obvious if you followed the advice of *never* using commas in the `from` clause:

```
SELECT name, COALESCE(fruit_name, 'all') as fruit_name
FROM person p LEFT JOIN
     fruit f
     ON p.preferred_fruit_id = f.fruit_id;
```

This assumes that all non-matching fruits in the `person` table should be `all`.  If you specifically want `-1`, then use a `CASE` expression instead.

Note that `-1` is a poor indicator for "all".  Either include "all" in the fruit table.  Or, use `NULL`.  These approaches would allow you to define proper foreign key constraints between the two tables.

Comment: Left join seems more appropriate. What if I wanted to use -2 as an indicator for 'no fruit' and -3 for 'all green fruits'? How should I approach?

Comment: @user54321 Why not just put (-1, all), (-2 ,'no fruit'), (3,'all green fruits') into the reference table?

Answer (score 0):

`-1` in `person.preferred_fruit` is a magic value. It may seem like a neat trick but stuff like this will ruin your database in the long run. Sooner or later somebody will mistake your magic value for a real value, and that's not good.

A better option is to use null instead.

But if you want to ascribe actual meaning to the value then put `-1, 'all'` in the `fruit` and enforce a foreign key.

That way you can do a straightforward look-up by joining `person` and `fruit`, which no needs no pfaffing around in the query to display the right data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
with person as(
select 'john' as name,3 as preferred_fruit_id from dual union all
select 'smith' as name,2 as preferred_fruit_id from dual union all
select 'sam' as name,-1 as preferred_fruit_id from dual
),
fruit as(
select 'apple' as fruit_name,3 as fruit_id from dual union all
select 'orange' as fruit_name,2 as fruit_id from dual
),
fruit2 as(
select fruit_name,fruit_id from fruit
union all
select 'all',-1 from dual
)
SELECT name, fruit_name
FROM person p,fruit2 f
WHERE p.preferred_fruit_id = f.fruit_id
```

OR this

```
with
fruit2 as(
    select fruit_name,fruit_id from fruit
    union all
    select 'all',-1 from dual
    )
    SELECT name, fruit_name
    FROM person p,fruit2 f
    WHERE p.preferred_fruit_id = f.fruit_id
```